# Does the New keyword call an inherited object's function?

Tags: c#, inheritance

In C#, if I have an object that inherits from another object, and the inherited object has a function with the same name as the base object, if I want to call the base object's function when the inherited object's function is called, should I use the new keyword? If not, how is the best way to call both functions?

Here is an example:

```
public partial class FormTest : Form
{
    public new void Refresh()
    {
        TestFunction();
    }
}
```

Basically, I am asking if the `Refresh` function of a `Form` object is also called when the `Refresh` function of a `FormTest` object is called. Also, is the `Refresh` function of a `Form` object called first, or is called after the `Refresh` function of a `FormTest` object.

Comment: _"if I want to call the base object's function when the inherited object's function is called"_ - depends on how you call it, or rather, what type the reference to `FormTest` is. Instead of making this an XY problem, can you explain what you're actually trying to do? Anyway no, a hiding method never automatically calls the hidden method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `new` keyword indicate explicit that the base class method `Refresh` should be hidden. `Refresh` method of the base class will not be called in this case. In order to call the base class method use `base.Refresh()` in `Refresh` method of the `FormTest` class.

Comment: How is the best way to call both functions?

Comment: @user3736648   `public override void Refresh()
    {
        base.Refresh();
    }`

Answer (score 1):

> if I want to call the base object's function when the inherited
>   object's function is called, should I use the new keyword?

No. `New` keyword is for hiding method in a parent class. And this is definitely not what you need. You should be overriding the `Refresh` method in child class and calling `Form.Refresh` method using `base` keyword.

```
public partial class FormTest : Form
{
    public override void Refresh()
    {
        TestFunction();
        base.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you use the `new` keyword instead of `override`, the method in the
>   derived class doesn’t override the method in the base class, it merely
>   hides it. In that case, code like this:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Base some method");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public new void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Derived some method");
    }
}    

Base b = new Derived();
Derived d = new Derived();
b.SomeOtherMethod();
d.SomeOtherMethod();
```

**Output** 
Base some method 
Derived some method

If you don’t specify either new or overrides, the resulting output is the same
as if you specified new, but you’ll also get a compiler warning (as you may not be aware that you’re
hiding a method in the base class method, or indeed you may have wanted to override it, and merely forgot to
include the keyword).

[Difference between override and new](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/whats-the-difference-between-override-and-new/)

Answer (score 0):

You have totally misunderstood the virtual and override. When you override a virtual method in your dervied class, it will never call the base class method when you are calling via dervied class instance.

IN your case, if the Refresh method is virtual in your Form class like:

```
public partial class Form
{
    public virtual void Refresh()
    {
        TestFunction();
    }
}
```

now if you override it in TestForm and if you call it via instance of TestForm it will alwas call Refresh method of TestForm.

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
   public override void Refresh()
   {
        TestFunction();
    }
}
```

Now if you run it like:

```
   Form form = new TestForm();
   form.Refresh(); // TestForm Reresh method will be called

   TestForm form = new TestForm();
   form.Refresh(); // TestForm Reresh method will be called
```

If you don't override and use the new keyword, then the case will be different:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
   public new void Refresh()
   {
        TestFunction();
    }
}
```

now if you call them you will see different results:

```
   Form form = new TestForm();
   form.Refresh(); // Form Reresh method will be called

   TestForm form = new TestForm();
   form.Refresh(); // TestForm Reresh method will be called
```